# MPMoviePlayerViewController locks up application with unusual appearance?

Tags: ios, iphone, video, youtube

So, I've tried this a number of ways with the same result.

I've tested by using a YouTube MP4 URL, such as:
[This](http://r2---sn-aigllns6.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?sparams=dur%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&mime=video%2Fmp4&upn=_JSKrqIiZ2o&fexp=900720%2C907263%2C934964%2C938028%2C938682%2C9406813%2C9407115%2C9407122%2C9407432%2C9408142%2C9408347%2C9408618%2C9408706%2C9409252%2C9410653%2C947233%2C948124%2C948703%2C951703%2C952612%2C952637%2C957201&source=youtube&pl=32&ratebypass=yes&initcwndbps=842500&nh=IgpwcjAzLmxocjE0KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&mm=31&signature=082FD24D3CF8482A81E69ABEAED7D103FCAC9286.E2B4B32395FE094A78EA2276F9804D20FEBC10DE&ipbits=0&expire=1430275555&sver=3&mt=1430253887&mv=m&ms=au&dur=108.553&ip=2a02%3A2498%3Ae000%3A85%3A94%3A%3A2&key=yt5&itag=18&id=o-AG6afO1aeuEHTIApBf7wYMMYOyvHD8CFSgpTCpACOvVu&title=Most%20intelligent%20Mimic%20Octopus%20in%20the%20world)

The way I do it looks pretty much like:

```
self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoUrlString]];
```

And then I play the video.  If I play the video and it goes fullscreen, the whole app locks up.  The video player appears, but parts of the status bar (such as the time and bars) disappear leaving only the carrier name.  The volume slider is only half there, and it loads indefinitely, and ignores any further touch input until I kill the app.  If I rotate the iPhone, the volume slider and the rest of the status bar reappear, but it still will not respond to touch or finish loading.  [Screenshot of issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTHOt.png)

If, instead, I pass the MPMoviePlayerViewController object to a UINavigationController with presentViewController:, the app seems to hang: until I rotate, then suddenly the video appears correctly and starts playing!  However, again, all touch input is ignored and the application is essentially locked.

This is one of the strangest issues I've troubleshot.

So I tried using tools others have built.  I tried XCDYouTubeKit and YKMediaKit using the Youtube ID instead of the direct link, with the *exact same result.*  After looking at their code, they both use MPMoviePlayerViewControllers.

What's happening here?  Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's surprising. Have you tried playing around with AV Foundation? It's a more modern media API than `MediaPlayer.framework`.

If you can target iOS 8 only, then `AVPlayerViewController` is a simple way to playback media via `AVPlayer`.

Comment: I was able to get it working with AVPlayerViewController.  Strange issue, but thank you!